# Include Faye Client in a Ionic 2 project with 'import'

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, ionic2, faye

I wanted to try Faye in a Ionic 2 project but I don't understand how I am going to add it to the project. As explained here https://faye.jcoglan.com/download.html, I would, if 'require' was available, just do something like:

```
var faye = require('faye');
```

If I was serving this Javascript from my webserver, I would just include a Script tag, pointing to the client.js as following:

```
<script src='http://localhost:8000/faye/client.js'></script>
```

I tried this in Ionic 2

```
import { Faye } from 'faye';
//...
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, platform: Platform, matchService: MatchService, faye : Faye) { //...
```

This code is generating this error:

> Typescript error: Cannot find name 'Faye'

How do I do it with 'import' so I can use Faye Browser CLient in this project?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a look at [faye exports at it's github source](https://github.com/faye/faye/blob/master/src/faye_node.js):

```
  var Faye = {
    VERSION:      constants.VERSION,
    Client:       require('./protocol/client'),
    Scheduler:    require('./protocol/scheduler'),
    NodeAdapter:  require('./adapters/node_adapter')
  };

  Logging.wrapper = Faye;
  module.exports = Faye;
```

Therefore, you can do

```
import { VERSION, Client, Scheduler, NodeAdapter } from 'faye'
```

Or, it you want to reach `Client` with `Faye.Client`:

```
import * as Faye from 'faye'
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally you would look for type declarations in npm @types and you would install packages as `npm install @types/package_name.`
But faye package doesnt seem to be added here.

According to IONIC docs [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/resources/third-party-libs/#creating-short-hand-definition)

you have to include the declaration in declarations.d.ts file while adding pure javascript module to Ionic 2.